# Compare two lists and import values from one to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets and what I need to do is to make a vba macro which will match each ID from the first sheet to the one in the second sheet, and copy its value next to it (in the second sheet). The cell location of the Values will be fixed, always in the same column (for example column 2).

For example the first sheet has some data with IDs and values like this:

```
 Sheet: Data

ID    Value
356   10000
441    5000
111    4000
```

And I have got the second sheet with only the ID's and not the values in different order, for example:

```
Sheet: Database
ID     Something   Value
111    Foo
356    Bar
441    Foo
```

And when you run the macro it should look like this:

```
Sheet: Database
ID     Something   Value
111    Foo         4000
356    Bar         10000
441    Foo         5000
```

Of course this is just an example, the real data has a few hundreds of rows, and **yes I have to use vba for this**.

Thank you upfront for your help :)

Comment: Have you ever tried a VLOOUP or INDEX/MATCH? They are the more basic and fundamental retrieval (aka lookup) formulas in Excel.

Comment: Browse around the site a bit, this question pops up multiple times a day although I’ll admit yours is written more clearly than most

Comment: I've tried searching unfortunately there was always something a bit different so I decided to create a new question, I believe many will find it very useful and clear in the future, don't understand why so many downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could do the trick:

```
Sub CompareCopy()
Dim FirstSheet As Worksheet
Set FirstSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim SecondSheet As Worksheet
Set SecondSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim lrowCompare As Integer
Dim Val As String
Dim ValCompare As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

lrow = FirstSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet1
lrowCompare = SecondSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet2

For i = 2 To lrow 'Loop through ID column in Sheet 1
    Val = FirstSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value 'Get ID Value in Sheet 1
    For j = 2 To lrowCompare 'Loop through ID column Sheet 2
      ValCompare = SecondSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value 'Get Value ID in Sheet 2
        If Val = ValCompare Then 'Compare the Values
            SecondSheet.Cells(j, 3) = FirstSheet.Cells(i, 2) 'Copy Value from Sheet1 to Sheet2
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

The code assumes that all the ID values are unique.

Comment: While I prefer a more efficient full column lookup like application.match, this more than adequately resolves the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Should be a decent start for @pomaaa to start with.

Comment: lCol = FirstSheet.Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column